# WorkItemStore.BatchSave method - how many workitems can be saved at once?

Tags: c#, tfs

I am using [WorkItemStore.BatchSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff734890%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to create multiple work items in TFS 2012. The documentation does not have any information on limits for this method - does anyone know what would be a safe batch size or if the method will handle any size internally?

Answer (score 0):

you have wis.MaxBulkUpdateBatchSize property which for me returns 200.